# nodejs express cluster restarting one by one

Tags: node.js, express, node-cluster

I am just being dumb, but I can't figure this out.
I have an express server, and I am using the cluster module provided by default (on 6.3.1). I am using apache benchmark 2.4 for testing: `ab -n 50000 -c 10 localhost:3000/api/v1/genders`

This is the situation, when someone changes in a config and sends a `kill -SIGHUP <master_pid>` , intercept it, kill the old worker and respawn new workers without closing the server.

So, I have two versions of the code, *in the first*:

I loop through an array of workers, `disconnect` each worker, and on `disconnect`, `kill` the worker, on `kill` a new process is forked. But the problem is at one point of time, there are no connection to server and so I get a connection refused error (61) and `ab` dies.

Also I read that `worker.disconnect` doesn't care shit about `client` connections .

*In the second process:*

I generated the new forks and then killed the old ones, one by one, while killing I didn't `disconnect` , I pass `worker.send('shutdown')` and then in the worker I do, `process.on('message' ...)` , in here, I do a `server.close` and a `process.exit` in the callback .. But now `ab` exists saying Connection reset by peer. What I don't understand is isn't server.close supposed to take care of the incoming connections that happened before the close?

**So,**

What is the exact way to solve this, where am I doing wrong ?

Here the two codes, in order (relevant bits):

[First](https://gist.github.com/argentum47/ce081cae13d565a3c972a9122b4cfe2c#gistcomment-1852418)

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict'

const cluster = require('cluster')
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length
const debug = require('debug')('api:www')

let clusterStore = {
  __store: [],
  insert: function(id) {
    this.__store.push(id)
    return this
  },
  get: function(id) {
    return this.__store.filter(s => s !== id)
  },
  update: function(prevId, newId) {
    let index = this.__store.indexOf(prevId);

    if(index > -1) delete this.__store[index]
    this.__store.push(newId);

    return this
  }
}

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // fork workers
  debug('master process (%s) ', process.pid);

  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    let fork = cluster.fork()
    clusterStore.insert(fork.id)
  }

  // if a worker dies, log it to the console and start another worker
  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    debug('worker (%s) died', worker.process.pid)

    let fork = cluster.fork()
    clusterStore.update(worker.id, fork.id)
  })

  // log when a worker starts listening
  cluster.on('listening', (worker, address) => {
    debug('worker (%s) started', worker.process.pid)
  })

  process.on('SIGHUP', function() {
    debug("respawning forks");

    clusterStore.get().forEach(function(id) {
      if(cluster.workers[id]) process.nextTick(() => { cluster.workers[id].disconnect() })
    })
  })

} else {
  worker()
}

function worker () {
  const app = require('../app')
  const http = require('http')

  const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000')
  app.set('port', port)

  const server = http.createServer(app)

  server.on('close', (err, data) => {
    debug("Disconnecting server")

    if(err) debug("Error occurs on server close (%s)", err.message)

    debug("Disconnected server")
    process.exit()
  })

  cluster.worker.on('disconnect', () => {
    debug("Disconnected child process (%s)", cluster.worker.process.pid)
    cluster.worker.kill()
  });

  server.listen(port)
  server.on('error', onError)
  server.on('listening', onListening)
}
```

[Second](https://gist.github.com/argentum47/ce081cae13d565a3c972a9122b4cfe2c#gistcomment-1852448): (changed bits)

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // fork workers
  debug('master process (%s) ', process.pid);

  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    let fork = cluster.fork()
    clusterStore.insert(fork.id)
  }

  // if a worker dies, log it to the console and start another worker
  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    debug('worker (%s) died', worker.process.pid)

    if(worker.exitedAfterDisconnect !== true) {
      let fork = cluster.fork()
      clusterStore.update(worker.id, fork.id)
    }
  })

  // log when a worker starts listening
  cluster.on('listening', (worker, address) => {
    debug('worker (%s) started', worker.process.pid)
  })

  process.on('SIGHUP', function() {
    debug("respawning forks");

    let oldClusters = clusterStore.get().slice()

    oldClusters.forEach(function(id) {
      let worker = cluster.workers[id]
      let timer;

      if(worker) {
        let fork = cluster.fork()
        clusterStore.update(worker.id, fork.id)
      }
    })

    oldClusters.forEach(id => {
      cluster.workers[id].send('shutdown')
    })
  })

} else {
  worker()
}

function worker () {
  const app = require('../app')
  const http = require('http')
  const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000')
  app.set('port', port)

  const server = http.createServer(app)

  process.on('message', (msg) => {
    if(msg ==='shutdown') {
      server.close(err => {
        if(err) debug("Error encountered while closing server (%s)", err.message)
        process.exit()
      })
    }
  })

  server.listen(port)
  server.on('error', onError)
  server.on('listening', onListening)
}
```